# Taylor Approximation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have got this question

> Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable at every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
>   $$f''(x) + f(x) = 0.$$
>   Show that if $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 0, $ and $\left|f(x)\right|\leq 24 $ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then for every  $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$\left|f(x)\right|\leq x^{4}$$

As all the example in my notes does given the equation of $f(x)$ so I have got no idea to deal with question that with unknown $f(x)$. Would you guys give a brief introduction about how to deal with this kind of question and show me details step in order to help me to learn it in details?

p.s. I am currently learning **Taylor Approximation and Error Estimation** in the section of **Differentiation and Its Applications**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. $f$ is four times differentiable, $f^{(3)}(x) = -f^{(1)}(x)$ and $f^{(4)}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$.
2. $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $0\leq n\leq 3$.
3. $|f^{(4)}(x)| = |f(x)| \leq 24$ for all $x$.
4. For any given $x$ Taylor's formula (as extension of Mean Value Theorem) provides a point $\zeta_x$ (between $0$ and $x$) such that:
   $$ |f(x)| = \left|\frac{1}{24} f^{(4)}(\zeta_x)x^4\right| $$